# How to do bitwise operations in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, bit-manipulation

I try to find out which bit is set using `BITAND`.

In database I save the user rights as BIGINT like `1101111` or `1110001`.

in the sample case I must find out the elemnts in the table if the third bit is set.
In this case. The query should find the first one.

How can I do that??

```
Select * from USERRIGHTS
WHERE BITAND(Rightmask , 4) = 1 ??????
```

Comment: Please define the 'first' row.  Unless you provide an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the returned rows is undefined.  Also, that rights segment is a multi-value column, which is inherently frowned on in a well-normalized system; for one thing, you're limited to 64 different values.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for the help. I saved the rightmask in an incorrect format. I found where the problem is. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It was silly to save the right mask in this form '1101111'.
I should save the data in decimal format.
In this case 1101111 = 111 (in decimal) or 1110001 = 113. I converted in my application the right mask into decimla an saved in that format.

And then it was possible to check if a bit position is set or not.

This query gives the all entries what i want :-):

Select * from USERRIGHTS
WHERE BITAND(Rightmask , 16) = 16 
(The third bit position is the **fifth** bit position from the right. This value should be used for the bitwise operations. 2^(5-1) = 16)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, UNIX, and Windows DB2 platforms, [bitwise operators](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052628.html) were introduced in version 9.5.

Comment: Okay.... but he already seems to know about the functions, so how does this answer his question?